# Recall, Precision and f2 compute in python tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, python, tensorflow, metric

How can I compute `precision`,`f2` and `recall` values in my code?

Please find my code below:

```
cost_function = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=y, labels=y_))
training_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost_function) 
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init) 
mse_history = []
accuracy_history = [] 
for epoch in range(training_epochs):
    sess.run(training_step, feed_dict={x: train_x, y_: train_y})
    cost = sess.run(cost_function, feed_dict={x: train_x, y_: train_y})
    cost_history = np.append(cost_history, cost)
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
    pred_y = sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: test_x})
    mse = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(pred_y - test_y))
    mse_ = sess.run(mse)
    mse_history.append(mse_)
    accuracy = (sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: train_x, y_: train_y}))
    accuracy_history.append(accuracy)
 
    print('epoch : ', epoch, ' - ', 'cost: ', cost, " - MSE: ", mse_, "- Train Accuracy: ", accuracy)
 
save_path = saver.save(sess, model_path)
print("Model saved in file: %s" % save_path)

plt.plot(accuracy_history)
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.show()
 
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
print("Test Accuracy: ", (sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: test_x, y_: test_y})))
```